# Как скриптом в Google Sheets перенести отфильтрованные данные на другой лист/таблицу

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, таблицы, фильтры

Кто может подсказать как можно выбрать отфильтрованные данные из одного листа и скопировать их на другой лист? те нужно выбрать только строки которые отобрались фильтрами.
Я написал такой код, но он получается выбирает весь диапазон подлежащий фильтрации.

```
  const sheetWork = 'График';   // Имя листа с рабочей информацией

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sWork = ss.getSheetByName(sheetWork);
  if (sWork == null) {
    ssUI.alert('Не найден лист с данными');
    return;
  }
  //sWork.activate();
  var rangeFilter = sWork.getFilter().getRange();
  Logger.log('Ширина диапазона: ' + rangeFilter.getWidth() + '\n' + 'Высота диапазона: ' + rangeFilter.getHeight());
```

Прошу помочь знающих)

Comment: Вот, кажется, аналогичный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645180/google-app-script-spreadsheet-how-to-get-filter-criteria) на enSO.

Comment: Спасибо!
но это несколько не то, там производится фильтрация скриптом, а у меня уже есть лист на котором применены фильтры и мне нужно только эти данные скопировать, те не все строки диапазона, а только показываемые.

Answer (score 1):

Просто скопируйте диапазон под фильтром. То, что невидимо, скопировано не будет.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetWork = 'График';   // Имя листа с рабочей информацией
  const sheetDest = 'График2';   // Имя листа, куда копировать

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  const sWork = ss.getSheetByName(sheetWork);
  const sDest = ss.getSheetByName(sheetDest);
  
  var rangeFilter = sWork.getFilter().getRange();
  rangeFilter.copyTo(sDest.getRange('A2'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL);
}
```

Ну и однострочник :)

```
function myFunction2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('График').getFilter().getRange().copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('График2').getRange('A2'));
}
```

Comment: Как все просто... )))
Спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос в догонку, не подскажите почему с опцией PASTE_NORMAL не копируются ширины столбцов? те данные скопировались, а ширины столбцов нет

Comment: Так задумано :) см. [Enum CopyPasteType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type?hl=ru). Для ширин используйте `PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS`

Comment: добавил строчку, а ширины столбцов все равно не изменились(

`
rangeFilter.copyTo(sDest.getRange('A2'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL);  rangeFilter.copyTo(sDest.getRange('A2'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS);
`

Comment: rangeFilter.copyTo(sDest.getRange('A2'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,**false**);

Comment: а подскажешь еще как-нибудь возможно комментарии то же скопировать?